# Using Concurrent thread in jmeter and AWS DLT with .jmx file - How do I provide inputs so that we can achieve 5000 RPS for 5 minutes duration

Tags: amazon-web-services, jmeter, load-testing, dlt

We have configured AWS for distributed load testing using - https://aws.amazon.com/solutions/implementations/distributed-load-testing-on-aws/

Our requirement includes achieving 5k RPS.

Please help me in understanding the [inputs that needs to be provided here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WMHpy.png)

When we consider the system supports 5k RPS then - What should be the Task Count, Concurrency, Ramp Up and Hold For values in order to achieve 5k RPS using AWS DLT.

We are also trying to achieve it using jmeter concurrent threads. Hoping someone could help with values and explaining the usage for the same.

Answer (score 0):

We don't know.

Have you tried read the documentation the link to which you provided yourself? I.e. for the **Concurrency** there is a chapter called [Determine the number of users](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/solutions/latest/distributed-load-testing-on-aws/determine-number-of-users.html) which suggests start with 200 and increase/decrease depending on the resources consumption.

The same applies to the Task Count, you may either go with a single container with default resources, [increase container resources](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/solutions/latest/distributed-load-testing-on-aws/increase-container-resources.html) or increase the number of containers.

The number of hits per second will mostly depend on your application response time, for example given 200 recommended users if response time will be 1 second - you will have 200 RPS, if response time will be 2 seconds - you will get 100 RPS, if response time will be 0.5 seconds - you will get 400 RPS, etc. See [What is the Relationship Between Users and Hits Per Second?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/what-relationship-between-users-and-hits-second) article for more comprehensive explanation if needed. The throughput can also be controlled on JMeter side using [Concurrency Thread Group](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ConcurrencyThreadGroup/) and [Throughput Shaping Timer](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ThroughputShapingTimer/) but again, the container(s) must have sufficient resources in order to produce the desired load.

With regards to ramp-up - again, we don't know. Personally I tend to increase the load gradually so I could correlate increasing load with other metrics. [JMeter documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#thread_group) recommends starting with ramp-up period in seconds equal to number of users.

The same for the time to hold the load, i.e. after ramping up to the number of users required to conduct the load of 5K RPS I would recommend holding the load for the duration of ramp-up period to see how the system behaves, whether it stabilizes when the load stops increasing, are the response times static or they go up, etc.